# Check if a c# list of objects contains an object with the same variable.

Tags: c#

I have a class which contains three values,

```
public class hitOBject {
    public string v1;
    public float v2;
    public float v3;
}
```

I dynamically create these objects during runtime which get stored in their own list.

```
 List<hitOBject> Detected = new List<hitOBject>();
```

However, when a new object is added to this list, I first need to check if if there is already a list which contains a a duplicate value. 
For example...

if I have 2 hitObjects

```
 obj1            obj2 
 v1 = bob        v1 = bob 
 v2 = 1f         v2 = 3f     
 v3 = 2.5f       v3 = 3.5f
```

and if I want to check wether V1 already exists in the list is there a method to do this?

I know that if it was a duplicated object I could just do the following code?

```
if(!Detected.Contains(object))
```

but as Im looking for a sub value this wont work?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use a `HashSet`, not a `List`, and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.If you are going to compare against only a single field/property in your class then specify that field only like:

```
public class hitOBject
{
    public string v1;
    public float v2;
    public float v3;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return ((hitOBject)obj).v1 == this.v1;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (v1 != null ? v1.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

and then you can use:

```
List<hitOBject> Detected = new List<hitOBject>();
Detected.Add(new hitOBject {v1 = "bob", v2 = 1f, v3 = 2.5f});

hitOBject secondObject = new hitOBject {v1 = "bob", v2 = 1f, v3 = 2.5f};
if (Detected.Contains(secondObject))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Alread Exists");
}
```

Since `List<T>.Contains` uses `Equals` to compare for equality, the override `Equals` method will return a bool based on comparison of field `v1`.

If you are going to have unique values in your `List` then it is better to use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) since it will only allow unique values based on `GetHashCode` and `Equals` implementation.

```
HashSet<hitOBject> Detected = new HashSet<hitOBject>();
Detected.Add(new hitOBject {v1 = "bob", v2 = 1f, v3 = 2.5f});
hitOBject secondObject = new hitOBject {v1 = "bob", v2 = 1f, v3 = 2.5f};
Detected.Add(secondObject);
```

In the above code, at the end, your `HashSet` will only contain a single item and `secondObject` will not be added to the `HashSet`.

If you don't want to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` then you can use a LINQ query to determine if an object exists in your list like:

```
hitOBject secondObject = new hitOBject {v1 = "bob", v2 = 1f, v3 = 2.5f};
if (Detected.Any(r => r.v1 == secondObject.v1))
{
    //Already exists
}
```

---

Another option is to leave your class as it is and implement [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) like

```
private sealed class hitObjectV1EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<hitOBject>
{
    public bool Equals(hitOBject x, hitOBject y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return string.Equals(x.v1, y.v1);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(hitOBject obj)
    {
        return (obj.v1 != null ? obj.v1.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

and then you can pass that in your `HashSet<T>` constructor like:

Also see: [General Naming Conventions C# - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
HashSet<hitOBject> Detected = new HashSet<hitOBject>(new hitObjectV1EqualityComparer());
```

Later adding items

```
Detected.Add(new hitOBject {v1 = "bob", v2 = 1f, v3 = 2.5f});
hitOBject secondObject = new hitOBject {v1 = "bob", v2 = 1f, v3 = 2.5f};
Detected.Add(secondObject);
```

You will end up with a single item in the `HashSet`.

You can use that Comparer with `List<T>.Contains` as well like:

```
List<hitOBject> Detected = new List<hitOBject>();
var MyEqualityComparer = new hitObjectV1EqualityComparer();
Detected.Add(new hitOBject {v1 = "bob", v2 = 1f, v3 = 2.5f});

hitOBject secondObject = new hitOBject {v1 = "bob", v2 = 1f, v3 = 2.5f};
if (Detected.Contains(secondObject, MyEqualityComparer))
{
    //Already Exists
}
else
{
    Detected.Add(secondObject);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!Detected.Any(o1 => o1.v1 == o2.v1 && o1.v2 == o2.v2 && o1.v3 == o2v3))
```

Please follow C# conventions. Variables (Detected) should be camelCase, classes (hitObject) should be PascalCase

If the list is big (more than 50 elements) consider using HashSet as @Servy suggested

Answer (score 0):

The any function is LINQ and looks for any match; if not any match, then add to the list... is that what you need?

```
if (!Detected.Any(Function(i) i.V1 = obj2.V1))
    Detected.Add(obj2);
```

Just add to get LINQ support:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement [the `IEquatable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) in your `HitObject`:

```
public class HitObject : IEquatable<HitObject>
{
    public string V1;
    public float V2;
    public float V3;

    public bool Equals(HitObject other)
    {
        return this.V1 == other.V1;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `Contains` method thusly:

```
List<HitObject> detected = new List<HitObject>();
detected.Add(new HitObject
{
    V1 = "bob",
    V2 = 1f,
    V3 = 2.5f
});
HitObject something = new HitObject
{
    V1 = "bob",
    V2 = 3f,
    V3 = 3.5f
};
if (!detected.Contains(something))
{
    // this line will not be executed
    detected.Add(something);
}
```